# Inputting issues with while(scanf): why does using getchar() keep the input going

Tags: c, input, getchar

I am trying to take 8 inputs through the `while(scanf)` process. At first, I tried the following piece of code :

```
while(scanf("Dia %d %d : %d : %d Dia %d %d : %d : %d",&day_start,&h1,&m1,&s1,&day_end,&h2,&m2,&s2)==8)
```

But, after one execution of the program, it terminates. Then, I used a `getchar()` after the input, like the following:

```
while(scanf("Dia %d %d : %d : %d Dia %d %d : %d : %d",&day_start,&h1,&m1,&s1,&day_end,&h2,&m2,&s2)==8)
{
    getchar();
    ......;
}
```

After doing this, the input kept going on after every execution. So, why does using `getchar()` keep the input going?

Is it because, the last enter was taken as an input and after using `getchar()`, the enter was taken in the `getchar()`?

Comment: I believe that is correct. getchar() reads in the newline character.

Comment: You should read an entire line using fgets and then use sscanf on the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this piece of code

```
while(scanf("Dia %d %d : %d : %d Dia %d %d : %d : %d",&day_start,&h1,&m1,&s1,&day_end,&h2,&m2,&s2)==8)
```

after the first execution the last enter-key pressed is taken as the first character of the second `scanf` which it must be `D` to continue, and this can't be reached.

while in this piece of code

```
while(scanf("Dia %d %d : %d : %d Dia %d %d : %d : %d",&day_start,&h1,&m1,&s1,&day_end,&h2,&m2,&s2)==8)
{
    getchar();
    ......;
}
```

the last enter-key goes to `getchar()` not to `scanf`

Comment: Yes. In the first iteration, the scanf took 8 inputs and returned 8 which made the program run. But, in the second iteration, scanf took only 1 input (the previous last enter). So, as scanf returned 1 which was false, the loop did not continue.

getchar() took the previous last enter and didn't let it get to the second iteration of the input.

Answer (score 1):

On the topic of scanf...

http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2008/02/07/scanf-and-why-you-should-avoid-using-it/

Now what specifically is happening when you used getChar? Do you mean it reaches an infinite loop, or it passes through the while loop and "keeps on going"?

Comment: I meant that it passes through the while loop and "keeps on going".